# PHP Binary to Hex with leading zeros

Tags: php, binary, hex

I have the follow code:

```
<?
$binary = "110000000000";
$hex = dechex(bindec($binary));
echo $hex;
?>
```

Which works fine, and I get a value of c00.

However, when I try to convert 000000010000 I get the value "10".  What I actually want are all the leading zeros, so I can get "010" as the final result.

How do I do this?

EDIT:  I should point out, the length of the binary number can vary.  So $binary might be 00001000 which would result it 08.

Comment: are you searching for something like `str_pad()` ?

Comment: To format string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Note that sprintf is nice but really *slow*

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but you cannot *calculate* leading zeros. This is just a formatting issue. Really wondering about your post (and the accepted answer). Please enlight me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend the requisite number of leading zeroes with something such as:

```
$hex = str_repeat("0", floor(strspn($binary, "0") / 4)).$hex;
```

What does this do?

1. It finds out how many leading zeroes your binary string has with `strspn`.
2. It translates this to the number of leading zeroes you need on the hex representation. Whole groups of 4 leading zero bits need to be translated to one zero hex digit; any leftover zero bits are already encoded in the first nonzero hex digit of the output, so we use `floor` to cast them out.
3. It prepends that many zeroes to the result using `str_repeat`.

Note that if the number of input bits is not a multiple of 4 this might result in one less zero hex digit than expected. If that is a possibility you will need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment, the length of the binary string can vary, so the amount of padding will need to change based on how long the binary is.

Comment: @MathewPatterson: This code automatically calculates the number of leading zeroes required by inspecting the binary input. Try it.

Comment: Oh, sorry, guess I didn't even try, just assumed I wasn't being specific enough!  Thanks!

Comment: `Whole groups of 4 leading zero bits need to be translated to one zero hex digit`. How can you *translate* a `0`?

Comment: @hek2mgl: The same way you translate e.g. a `f` to the decimal digit sequence 15 (note that I am explicitly talking about *digits*, not numbers, everywhere). If you don't like my choice of verb I am open to better suggestions.

Comment: Ok, understood.. Your answer is good +1, but I still think the OP asks for something that sounds weird to me, as even if is just a `1` it would consume `PHP_INT_SIZE * 2 - 1` *zeros* (check my , updated, answer)

Comment: @hek2mgl: It sounds weird to me as well, but it can be legit. Also, this requirement is the only thing that makes the whole affair unusual and thus "interesting". :-)

Answer (score 12):

You can do it very easily with [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
// Get $hex as 3 hex digits with leading zeros if required. 
$hex = sprintf('%03x', bindec($binary));

// Get $hex as 4 hex digits with leading zeros if required. 
$hex = sprintf('%04x', bindec($binary));
```

To handle a variable number of bits in $binary:

```
  $fmt = '%0' . ((strlen($binary) + 3) >> 2) . 'x';
  $hex = sprintf($fmt, bindec($binary));
```

Comment: Just to add, if you want to handle different lengths of $binary, then something like:

Answer (score 7):

Use [`str_pad()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) for that:

```
// maximum number of chars is maximum number of words 
// an integer consumes on your system
$maxchars = PHP_INT_SIZE * 2; 
$hex = str_pad($hex, $maxchars, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: You should dynamically calculate `$maxchars` based on the number of characters in `$binary` with `floor( strlen( $binary) / 4)`.

Comment: `0==0` in every number system. This cannot be *calculated*. It's just a formatting issue

Comment: Indeed it does, but I have absolutely no clue how that relates to my comment. Imagine your input is `$binary = "0000000000000000000000000001";`. Your solution fails, as the proper output is `0000001`, [you would get `0001`](http://viper-7.com/5GaWNg).

Comment: ??????????????????????????????????? ... `0000000000000000000000000001 == 1` and nothing more. Can you explain, how you calculated this?

Comment: Reread the OP: *What I actually want are **all the leading zeros**...*

Comment: Yeap, I already dropped a comment. The question is hard to get as this cannot being calculated. its a formatting issue. But as I said, I'm open to  get enlighted, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30026/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-nickb)